# Unable to display product list by specific category in magento 1.7

Tags: magento

I followed all the steps to display the products list by specific category, but unable to display. I created a CMS page in the admin section and copy the code below to display products from category id 49

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="49" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But not showing any thing ... please go to http://coralconcept.in/pant-skirt/

I created a parent category under default category which has 'Is Anchor' Yes and under that i have this category containing category ID 49 and 'Is Anchor' Yes . Have I done anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to white-list block catalog/product_list.

you can do it via  system/permission/block and add click new block

and type block

```
name =>catalog/product_list  system/permission/block and Is Allowed =>  yes
```

Also please clear cache and re-indexing if require.

Thanks,

Sam

Oh sorry this is for 1.9 however could you please make sure that there is atleast product assigned to 49 category and cache is disable form BE

Comment: Hello Sam .... Yes I have lots of product under this category , You can see the products from here http://coralconcept.in/clothing?cat=49 , And cache is disabled .  Any idea why the products is not showing in CMS page? Do i need any settings change for it.  Thanks